# SetLenient(false) with Year

Tags: java

I am using DateFormat setLenient() to parse the string and validate the date. But I am not able to validate the year even if I am passing the wrong year like 2digits or 3digits year.Please tell me how to parse year for 4 digits only if i have given date through scanner.

```
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter date");
    String date1 = sc1.nextLine();
    String pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    DateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    formatter.setLenient(false);
    try {
         {
            formatter.parse(date1);
            System.out.println("valid date");
        }
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.out.println("invalid date");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `DateTimeFormatter` instead: `DateTimeFormatter` is a lot stricter in what strings are accepted and what are not.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
try {
    formatter.parse(date1);
    System.out.println("valid date");
} catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
    System.out.println("invalid date");
}
```

`setLenient` doesn't really have much to do with whether years are two-digit or four-digit. "Lenient" here means the same thing as in `Calendar`. It is used to decide whether a date like `2019-01-32` would automatically become `2019-02-01`, which I find to be rarely useful. If you would like this non-lenient `SimpleDateFormat` behaviour in `DateTimeFormatter` as well, you need to use:

```
String pattern = "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)
                                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
try {
    LocalDateTime.parse(date1, formatter);
    System.out.println("valid date");
} catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
    System.out.println("invalid date");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Range check

Charlemagne was born 2 April 742, and the year is usually given as three digits. I don’t think I have ever seen 0742. Would you require your user to enter it with a leading zero?

Maybe your problem is a different one: you don’t want to accept year 999 or earlier as input. For most applications that’s a good and valid restriction. If so, I’d consider: what is the valid range of dates? Not only how many digits should a year have (`yyyy` will also accept 5 or 6 digits).

So in addition to what @Sweeper says in the other answer (which has all the advantages: java.time, the modern Java date and time API is so much nicer to work with), do a range check. For example:

```
    final LocalDateTime minDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(1849, Month.DECEMBER, 22, 13, 30);
    final LocalDateTime maxDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2032, Month.MAY, 5, 12, 0);
    String pattern = "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)
            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
    try {
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date1, formatter);
        if (dateTime.isBefore(minDateTime) || dateTime.isAfter(maxDateTime)) {
            System.out.println("invalid date");
        } else {
            System.out.println("valid date");
        }
    } catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
        System.out.println("invalid date");
    }
```